# setting state using usestate doesn't call render method

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state of a class using `useState()`, but when I call the set function the render method of the class doesn't get called.
Also when I call the set function `useEffect` is called twice.

```
const InputSlider = (state) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    sliderValue: 0
  });
  const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, 
      sliderValue: newValue
    }))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("state updated ", value)
  });
  return(
    <Slider
      onChange={handleSliderChange}
      defaultValue={0}
      //value ={value}
      getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
      valueLabelDisplay="auto"
      min={state.state.min}
      max={state.state.max}
      step={state.state.step}
    />
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sliderValue: 0
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className ="slider">
        <InputSlider state = { this.state } />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using 'sliderValue' in your code?

Comment: I think your "value" assigned to Slider field "value" is an object, so you have to assign ```value.sliderValue```. I advice you to use properly the name of your variables and props passed to your component, in order to not go crazy.

Comment: @MonikaMangal i am passing it as props to another class.